# How to access data from different child's of firebase database?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to retrieve particular child at a particular condition. 
Also, retrieve all data from a particular child.
Here is code that I am using. but it accesses last child at any condition.

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
            DatabaseReference chilDBR = databaseReference.child(firebaseChild);
            chilDBR.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {...}
```